# Organize the data for Heatmap.2 plot

Tags: r, dataframe, heatmap

I'm new with Heatmap plots, and trying to craete one with a dataframe I have.
I can'r figure out how to organize the data to give me a sensible heatmap plot.
I have the below head of my dataframe:

```
   sample_name                         merge         frequency
1:      2006-2             chr1_65311238_T_C            0.8103
2:      2006-2      chr15_90630438_ATCA_GTCG            0.7500
3:      2006-2            chr12_46246052_C_T            0.8602
4:      2006-2      chr12_46245224_CGCA_AGCT            0.9017
5:      2006-2 chr11_3720379_CACAGGG_TACGGGA            0.6308
6:      2006-2        chr7_152027701_ACA_ACG            0.8491
```

And the below script:

```
library(data.table) 

setwd("G:\\My Drive\\Netta\\gm_analysis")

ra_df <- fread("G:\\My Drive\\Netta\\gm_analysis\\RA064_gm.csv",
           select=c(9,10,11))
library("gplots")

ra_df$merge = as.numeric(as.factor(ra_df$merge))
ra_df$sample_name = as.numeric(as.factor(ra_df$sample_name))
my_matrix <- data.matrix(ra_df)

test_plot <- heatmap.2(my_matrix, scale = "column")
test_plot
```

I get really weird plot.

In the above script I converted the "sample_name" and the "merge" columns to numeric. I have a total of 3 types of samples.

I'd like that the 3 types of samples will be on the x axis, the merge on the y axis, and the fill of the heatmap according to the "frequency".

How should I do it with Heatmap.2 ?

Comment: Is it compulsory to use `gplots` and `heatmap.2` or you can think to use other packages?

Comment: I'm open to use other packages. I just need to plot heatmap for my data...you have other ideas?